# How to pass partial view textbox value to parent view hidden field?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

## Partial view

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// filling popup value
function DisplaySectorInfo(hdnAnyRowSelected_Add, hdnSector, hdnSTNFrom, hdnSTNTo ) {
    var Sector = $('#' + hdnSector + 1).val();      
    document.getElementById('txtSectorNo').value = Sector;      

    PopUpLayer('dvSectorInfo', 'show');

}
</script>

    <div id="dvSectorInfo" >
         <input id= "txtSectorNo" name="txtSectorNo" type="text" value=" "  maxlength="3" />
         <input type="button" value="OK" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"   />
    </div>
```

The entered text box value need to pass parent view.

Comment: What are you trying to ask? put your code properly in a readable format

Comment: Can you provide html code where you 1st enter the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent view you can retrieve the value of the input in PartialView because it is part of the DOM. Since you are using jQuery you can add to your "parent" View:

```
<script>
$(function(){//shorthand for document.ready
    $('#myHiddenField').val($('#txtSectorNo').val()); //set a hidden field to the value of txtSectorNo
});
</script>
```

But you are waiting for data input from a user. So really you need to wait for your "btnSubmit" button to be clicked. You could bind a click event in your PartialView or your "parent" View. Its all about the HTML elements existing on the page in the client's browser and organizing your Views.

It is best, IMO to place this logic in your "parent" cshtml View as your partial should, in this case, just contain a section of meaningful content you are trying to organize, your "parent View can contain all Javascript functions and jQuery binding in a @section scripts{}

So I would have your parent View look like this:

```
@Html.Partial("SectionPartial);

@section scripts{
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
        $('#myHiddenField').val($('#txtSectorNo').val()); //set a hidden field to the value of txtSectorNo
    });
});
</script>
<script>
// filling popup value
function DisplaySectorInfo(hdnAnyRowSelected_Add, hdnSector, hdnSTNFrom, hdnSTNTo ) {
    var Sector = $('#' + hdnSector + 1).val();      
    document.getElementById('txtSectorNo').value = Sector;      

    PopUpLayer('dvSectorInfo', 'show');

}
</script>
}//end section scripts
```

And your partial View only needs to be:

```
<div id="dvSectorInfo" >
     <input id= "txtSectorNo" name="txtSectorNo" type="text" value=" "  maxlength="3" />
     <input type="button" value="OK" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit"   />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing doubt Brian. Its working fine.

Comment: No problem, glad things make more sense now